# OpenCV Viz module displaying point cloud crashing

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, point-clouds

This code has been crashing for a couple of days now and I don't really see why that's happening. I am trying to visualize some 3D points of type CV_64FC3 that are generated from opencv triangulation method. [viz::wcloud documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d82/classcv_1_1viz_1_1WCloud.html)
my points3Dhomogeneous is a [4153, 1] with 3 channels (CV_64FC3) and the points3DhomogColor is also a [4153, 1] with 3 channels (CV_64FC3).
So if I m using the color matrix it crashing when creating the point cloud in this line (`viz::WCloud cw(points3Dhomogeneous, points3DhomogColor);`) and if I just create the point cloud with the same color for all point (e.g `viz::Color::white()`) it shows the point cloud but crashes at the display line level (`myWindow.showWidget("cloud", cw);`).

```
viz::Viz3d myWindow("Viz Demo");
while (!myWindow.wasStopped())
{
    //Interact with window
    myWindow.showWidget("Coordinate Widget", viz::WCoordinateSystem());
    //Create a cloud widget
    viz::WCloud cw(points3Dhomogeneous, points3DhomogColor);
    //Display it in a window
    myWindow.showWidget("cloud", cw);
    //Event loop for 1 millisecond
    myWindow.spin();
    //myWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
}
```

If anyone has any idea or suggestion I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your event loop (`while (!myWinsdow.wasStopped()`) should not recreate a `viz::WCloud` nor should it call `showWidget`. These operations must be done before entering it. If you want to refresh a point cloud that was already displayed because some of its point have changed then I think you must remove the widget before adding it again.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel that makes sense I m very new to using viz module. I did get rid of the breaking I was having but even though I moved those two lines before the loop the program breaks at the end when I press 'q'. It breaks at this level "cv::viz::vtkVizInteractorStyle::~vtkVizInteractorStyle() {}" I also tested with the array of colors but it doesn't work. If you have any idea on how to solve that I would appreciate it, I couldn't find some thorough tutorials or documentation that could help.